# Node dynamics–entry and exit in STATNET / TERGM

Tags: statnet

I have temporal network data and trying to model the formation and dissolution of ties using TERGM (a function in STATNET package in R). The tutorial provided [here](https://statnet.github.io/Workshops/tergm_tutorial.html) is very helpful, but it deals with balanced panel data (i.e., the same set of vertices over time).

My question is how can I make this function (TERGM) work when I have different set of vertices over time. In other words, actors exit and new actors enter into my network over time.
Here is the code I run:

`samp.fit2 <- stergm(samplist, formation= ~edges, dissolution = ~edges, estimate = "CMLE", times=1:3)`

And this is the error message I get:

> Error in networkOperatorSetup(x = e1, y = e2) : 
>     Non-conformable networks (must have same numbers of vertices for elementwise operations).

Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?